# c# Disable cursor in Rich Text Box

Tags: c#, pointers, richtextbox, readonly

How do you set your richtextbox to not show a cursor/textlocator while on readonly. I.ex. so that even if you click on it, the flashing pointer doesnt appear.

Note: I DONT mean that the cursor should be hidden when hovering over it.

Answer (score 5):

Change your `Cursor` property:

```
<RichTextBox Cursor="None"/>
```

Or if you still want the cursor visible, use:

```
<RichTextBox Cursor="Arrow"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

Depends on what application you are creating: Winforms or WPF?

**Winforms:**

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool HideCaret(IntPtr hWnd);
private void TextBoxGotFocus(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    HideCaret(myControl.Handle);
}
```

**WPF:**

```
<RichTextBox Cursor="Arrow"/>
```

note: 
wpf method forces the cursor to be in arrow form.
The Winforms method just hides the Caret cursor.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`HideCaret`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648403%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.  You'll need to add a reference to user32.dll, then you can use something like:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool HideCaret(IntPtr hWnd);

private void TextBoxGotFocus(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    HideCaret(myControl.Handle);
}
```

Note that normally there is still a point to the caret; it allows the user to select text from within the control, and to arrow up/down to scroll.